# Nose: generator for TestCase-based classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I want to create a generator for variations of a TestCase-derived class.

What I tried is this:

```
import unittest

def create_class(param):
    class Test(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            pass

        def test_fail(self):
            assert False
    return Test

def test_basic():
    for i in range(5):
        yield create_class(i)
```

What I get is this:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_1.test_basic
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 268, in setUp
    try_run(self.test, names)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 478, in try_run
    return func()
TypeError: setUp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Yielding instances instead of classes (`yield create_class(i)()`) leaves me with this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_1.test_basic
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/unittest/case.py", line 492, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/unittest/case.py", line 423, in run
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'runTest'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When instantiating a `TestCase` you should pass the method name of the test:

```
yield create_class(i)('test_fail')
```

Otherwise the name defaults to `runTest`(and thus the last error you got).

Also note that there is a strange interaction between test generators and `TestCase`. With the following code:

```
import unittest

def create_class(param):
    class Test(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            pass

        def test_fail(self):
            print('executed')
            assert False
            print('after assert')

    return Test

def test_basic():
    for i in range(5):
        yield create_class(i)('test_fail')
```

I obtain this output:

```
$ nosetests -s
executed
.executed
.executed
.executed
.executed
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.004s

OK
```

As you can see the test does not fail, even though the `assert` works. This is probably due to the fact that `TestCase` handles the `AssertionError` but `nose` does not expect this to be handled and thus it cannot see that the test failed.

This can be seen from the documentation of [`TestCase.run`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.run):

> Run the test, collecting the result into the test result object passed as `result`. If result is omitted or None, a temporary result
>   object is created (by calling the `defaultTestResult()` method) and
>   used. The result object is not returned to `run()`‘s caller.
>
> ```
> The same effect may be had by simply calling the TestCase instance.
> ```

So, `nose` doesn't see that the objected yielded by the generator is a `TestCase` which should be handled in a special manner, it simply expects a callable. The `TestCase` is run, but the result is put into a temporary object that is lost, and this eats all test failures that happen inside the tests. Hence yielding `TestCase`es simply doesn't work.

Comment: What if I have multiple methods in `Test`? Passing those explicetly seems like a big violation of the DRY principle…

Comment: @dom0 I think you should read carefully the nose documentation regarding [test generators](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators). You are mixing things up. `TestCase`es are *not* designed to be used this way, and obviously this result in suboptimal code.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the codes you provides. I received no error. The version I use is python2.7. System is ubuntu12.10. Maybe you need to check with python2.7.

Comment: Okay then it seems like a bug to me. I use nose on Python 3.3, maybe that's the issue. I can't (and don't) want to switch the project back to Python 2.x, so I just try working around this issue in the mean time…